# Altering csv function to return specific data?

Tags: python, jython, jes

The function below takes a csv file that is formatted `grade type,grade type number,grade`. Example the first 10 are `assignment,assignment number,grade`. The function puts these first 10 into a list.

What I'm trying to get the function to do is return:
`highest grade,assignment number` and 
 
`lowest grade,assignment number`

```
def assigment(file):
  res=[]
  f = open(file,'r+')
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for i, line in enumerate(reader):
      if i < 10:    
         res.append((line[0],int(line[1]),int(line[2])))
         print max(res)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a few lines of the input file as well as your desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If index `[2]` is the grade for each assignment, and it is numeric, you can use the `sort` function as follows:

```
import csv


def assigment(file):

    res = []

    with open(file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for line in reader[:10]:
            res.append((line[0],int(line[1]),int(line[2])))

    res.sort(key= lambda x: x[2])

    max = res[-1]
    min = res[0]
```